# iOS open pdf use my own app setting does not work

Tags: ios, pdf, uti

I am developing an iOS app for pdf view, I want that when user open an email(I use gmail for test) attachment pdf file then there will be a menu like "open in" include my app, I follow this guide [ios adding a custom type](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html) and this is my setting, [image: Exported UTIs setting] , I rebuild my project and open the gmail attachment pdf file,when I touch and hold it shows nothing, and I single tap the attachment icon it will be opened by a default app, not my app, so I don't know what's wrong. Are there any mistake in my setting or my test device has setted the defalut application to open pdf files? If so how can I change it? Thank you!

Comment: Read this example https://mobiforge.com/design-development/importing-exporting-documents-ios

and see the list to confirm URI by Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, I follow importing documents part and it works, but the code needs to be changed for my own case.

Comment: I think you can answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Ok I have added in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow example

[Example](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/importing-exporting-documents-ios)

Also, see the list to confirm URI by Apple

[URI list](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html)